# show wp_postmeta in woocommerce order dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i try to show a specific meta_value based on post_id and meta_key in woocommerce order dashboard:

First i create a new column:

```
function mb_set_order_note_column( $columns ) {
  $columns['parcel_delivery'] = __('DHL','TEXTDOMAIN');
  return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 'mb_set_order_note_column', 99 );
```

After i have tried to get the specific value from wp_postmeta database

```
function mb_show_order_note_columns( $column_name, $post_id ) {         
 switch ( $column_name ) {
  case 'parcel_delivery':
  $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
  $delivery = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_parcel_delivery_opted_in' );
  print $delivery ;
  break;
 }
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'mb_show_order_note_columns', 10, 2 );
```

this shows only the customer notes from wp_post database. how to change to get specific value...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I see your custom meta key is _parcel_delivery_opted_in. So to get this value from wp_postmeta with order id and meta key,

$delivery = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_parcel_delivery_opted_in', true ); // like _billing_email meta
3rd parameter true will return single value, if you omit third parameter an array will be returned.